# Oracle: how to specify non-default backup location during RMAN restore

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, rman

Oracle 19c on Windows.
RMAN scheduled backups go to FRA here: D:\oracle\recovery.
I have another backup in D:\backup\ which I want to restore. I need to be able to "tell" Rman to look into non-default location. Here is what I have so far:

```
shutdown immediate;
startup nomount;
show parameter control_files;
exit;
rman target /
restore controlfile from 'D:\BACKUP\';
alter database mount;

-- full recovery
run{
restore database;
recover database;
alter database open resetlogs;
}
```

At which point I specify backup location and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rman> catalog start with D:\backup';
-> Yes to comfirm and here we go

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no default location for backup.

There could be locations RMAN is aware of and do not aware.

How to check it?

Via `list backup` command

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/rcmrf/LIST.html#GUID-2BAB704C-A3C9-4F76-8D96-4BD961FBEF2E

Where RMAN store information about backups?

- In catalog database or
- in controlfile

So in your case you use controlfile. I don't think RMAN is smart enough to find the best backup of controlfile so I guess you must provide the file to restore from and not just folder.

How to let RMAN know that some backups exists on D:\BACKUP ?
by command `CATALOG`

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/rcmrf/CATALOG.html#GUID-6E337759-9860-463A-BF7C-8512B272B8E1

As Duong mention you can catalog everything in D:\BACKUP by `catalog start with`

Beware it will prompt you for every file so you can suppress it via `NOPROMPT` parameter

After you catalog all backups, you can run `list backup` again to make sure rman aware of backups and perform full restore.